# What is the window class name assigned by Visual Studio when creating .NET form?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows, winforms

As in VC++ when creating a window we need to create a window class and use RegisterClass or RegisterClassEx to register. But in .NET we don't have this step.

So I wonder what the default window class name assigned by Visual Studio when creating a form?

As I've tracked out, the window class name assigned by Visual Studio is somewhat similar to this:
**WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.1ca0192_r13_ad1**

I want to change this default window class name, any idea?

Comment: Why would you want to change it?

Comment: i need to check whether a certain form is the form created by my application

Comment: That doesn't answer @André's question, Paul. You don't have to be able to change it in order to check whether it exists. Simply find out what class name you're supposed to look for, and then look for it. On the other hand, André's question is not important for answering *your* question. Keep in mind, though, that there are probably better ways to do whatever it is you really need. You apparently want to find out whether a given window is one created by your application. You should have asked *that*, not about window classes.

Comment: because i have 2 applications, 1 is written in vc++, the other in c#. the vc++ app must know whether the c# form is a proper one to communicate. i can only think of this checking window class name solution. don't know if there's a better approach

Comment: That's fine, Paul, but you don't have to be able to *change* the class name. Just run your .Net program, find out what the window's class name is, and then use that in your other program. What you *really* want, though, are techniques for *[interprocess communication between C# and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+interprocess+communication)*. (Besides, you *can't* change the window class name. Apparently, you can change *part* of it by setting your form's [`CreateParams.ClassName`](http://tinyurl.com/3ookdvo) property.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Window class names are automatically generated.  You cannot change them, even though CreateParams lets you set the ClassName property.  Nor can an external program ever guess the auto-generated name correctly, part of it is generated from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetHashCode().

You'll need another way to identify the window.  Not much available, but you could pinvoke SetProp() to associate an arbitrary string to a window.  And test if it is present with GetProp().  The SDK article [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633561%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: tks Hans, GetProp & SetProp can can do this identification job! :)